# Link to Play Store App

Tags: android

I'm trying to link into the Play Store app on an Android device and not the web link. I've used the URL Google supplies here: http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html and neither work on a Nexus 6. The market:// link just pulls up a google search page, and the https:// link goes to the web play store, not the app play store.

Any ideas how to open the app and not the web apge?

Edit: I am launching the link directly from the browser. I need to be able to open the Play Store both from the browser and from my app. I am testing using intents now for opening from the app -- I suspect that will work.

However, is it possible to open the play store app from the browser? Or can you only be redirected to the web play store from the browser.

Comment: Which action and category are you using for the intent?

Comment: So I'm actually not using an intent, I'm just plugging it directly into my browser for quick testing - I'm guessing that could be the reason?

Comment: Not all browsers support link to intent conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
final String appPackageName = "com.example"; // your application package name
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
```